# Deriving the formula for the height of a trapezoid

Tags: geometry

The bases of a trapezoid have lengths $a$ and $b$, and its legs have lengths $c$ and $d$. A formula for the height is
\begin{equation*}
h = \frac{
\sqrt{(-a + b + c + d)(a - b + c + d)(a - b - c + d)(a - b + c - d)}
}
{2\vert a - b \vert} .
\end{equation*}
The formula is reminiscent of Heron's Formula.  I would like to see a derivation of it.

Comment: I have never seen this formula in my life. Is this the way that other people learn geometry?

Comment: @Andres Mejia   I have read several books on plane and spherical geometry, and I didn't see any formula for the height of an arbitrary trapezoid and for the lengths of the two diagonals of an arbitrary trapezoid.  This is new to me, too.

Comment: @Andres Mejia  Here is a web site for the formulas.  `MathWorld.wolfram.com/Trapezoid.html`.

Comment: Your title mentions diagonals. Do you mean you have similar formulas for them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula "is reminiscent of Heron's Formula" because it is based on Heron's Formula.

One formula for the area of a triangle is

$$A=\frac 12bh$$

and Heron's formula gives

$$A=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$$

where $s$ is the semiperimeter given by

$$s=\frac{a+b+c}2$$

Here is a diagram for the derivation for the height of your trapezoid, assuming that $a>b$ (i.e. $a$ is the larger base and $b$ is the smaller one).

[image]

Note that I constructed a line segment (in green) parallel to side $c$ through the end of side $b$ that is not on side $c$. This line segment also has length $c$, of course, and it makes a triangle with sides $a-b,\ c,\ d$ that has the same height $h$ (dotted) as the trapezoid.

Using those sides of the triangle rather than $a,\ b,\ c$ gives us the equations

$$A=\frac 12(a-b)h$$

and

$$A=\sqrt{s(s-[a-b])(s-c)(s-d)}$$

where

$$s=\frac{(a-b)+c+d}{2}$$

Solving for $h$ in $A=\frac 12(a-b)h$, substitutions, and simplifications give us

$$\begin{align}
h &= \frac{2}{a-b}A \\[2ex]
  &= \frac{2}{a-b}\sqrt{s(s-[a-b])(s-c)(s-c)} \\[2ex]
  &= \frac{2}{a-b}\sqrt{\frac{(a-b)+c+d}{2}\left(\frac{(a-b)+c+d}{2}-[a-b]\right)\left(\frac{(a-b)+c+d}{2}-c\right)\left(\frac{(a-b)+c+d}{2}-d\right)} \\[2ex]
  &= \frac{2}{a-b}\sqrt{\frac{a-b+c+d}{2}\left(\frac{-a+b+c+d}{2}\right)\left(\frac{a-b-c+d}{2}\right)\left(\frac{a-b+c-d}{2}\right)} \\[2ex]
  &= \frac{1}{2(a-b)}\sqrt{(a-b+c+d)(-a+b+c+d)(a-b-c+d)(a-b+c-d)} \\[2ex]
  &= \frac{\sqrt{(-a+b+c+d)(a-b+c+d)(a-b-c+d)(a-b+c-d)}}{2|a-b|} \\[2ex]
\end{align}$$

which is your formula.

It is easily seen that if we assume $a<b$ we end up with the same result, thanks to the absolute value in the denominator. If $a=b$ this formula fails, but we then get a parallelogram whose height is not uniquely determined, so no formula is possible for $a=b$.

I tested this formula in Geogebra, and it checks.

Comment: Very nice construction!

Comment: My apologies for misquoting the formula from the web site that I provided.  I edited the file so that other viewers of this post will not be confused.

Comment: @Adelyn: You are right. Done! I will also modify my answer, now that you have corrected the formula in your question.

Comment: If more formulas regarding trapezoids piques your interest now, see my post at "The formula for the area of two triangles determined by the diagonals of a trapezoid."

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link http://villemin.gerard.free.fr/Wwwgvmm/Geometri/Trapeze.htm to a (french language) website mentioning this formula (go almost to the last page) under the form:

$$h=\dfrac{\sqrt{((b+d)^2-(a-c)^2)((a-c)^2-(b-d)^2)}}{2(a-c)}$$

**Edit Translation of a small part of the site of Gérard Villemin:**

**Isosceles trapezoid**

Characterization or necessary and sufficient conditions for a trapezoid to be isosceles

- Two angles adjacent to the same base are equal.
- Non parallel sides have the same length.
- The measures of the two diagonals are the same.
- The two bases have a common perpendicular bissector, which is besides an axis of symmetry of the trapezoid.
- If the trapezoid is isosceles, the sum of opposite angles is $\pi$.

**Alignment: theorem of trapezoid**

Trapezoid  : ABCD

Sides intersect in point : m

Diagonals intersect in : s

Bases midpoints : n and t.

Theorem : The four points m, n, s, and t associated with the trapezoid are aligned.

**Avec les diagonales -> with the diagonals**

Due to the fact that sides AB and CD are parallel, triangles APB et CPD are similar and diagonals intersect themselves in the same proportions p/p'=q/q'.

**Relationship between P and Q diagonals and sides**

A convex quadrilateral is a trapezoid if and only if the product of the areas of triangles "created" by one diagonal is equal to the product "created" by the other one: $(V+U)...$. Developing...But V=T, validation the affirmation.

Yes, the third column gives examples.

Comment: That is an unusual web site.  I don't speak French, but I will try to translate the part that is relevant to the formula for the height of a trapezoid.

Comment: Yes, there is a formula for the lengths of the diagonals, and there is a formula for the intersection of the diagonals.  Both are found at `MathWorld.wolfram.com/Trapezoid.html`.  No demonstrations for them are provided, though.

Comment: If you need a translation, I can do it (french is my native language)

Comment: Yeah, I would appreciate a translation.  Are the demonstrations of any formula here presented as a table?  How about a translation of the table in "Alignement: Theorems of Trapezoids" and "Avec les diagonales"?   (What are the numbers in the third column of the table in under the category of isosceles trapezoids?  Is it saying "if one base has length 50 and if another base has length 18 ...  "?)

Comment: I have translated what you need as an appendix to my little text.

Comment: Thanks for the translation.  The Alignment Theorem is particularly interesting.  Also, in the section "With the Diagonals," there is a theorem stated as "the relationship between the diagonals and the  sides."  It states that the sum of the squares of the diagonals is equal to the sum of the squares of the legs of the trapezoid and twice the product of its bases.   Do you know a demonstration for these?

Comment: In your translation of the Alignment Theorem, you have "m, n, s, et t" instead of "m, n, s, and t."  Ooops!  I will delete this comment after the correction.